# What else do i have to do after the Gitlab Omnibus installation?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

im trying to get Gitlab to work, but obviously im missing something in the process of installation. I followed this installation guide: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404

to install it on my ubuntu 14.04 server.

Are there any further steps i have to take before it works? Because when i go to git.codefighters.org it shows the apache index.html page.

I changed the external_url part in the gitlab.rb file, but i notices that nearly all other lines in that file are commented out.

Thanks to everyone who can help me to solve this!

Comment: No further steps required. Did you install it on a clean server? GitLab uses NGINX so Apache might be enabled due to a pre configured image. If you want it to work with Apache read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-proxy-gitlab-nginx-into-apache2 if not let us know to further assist you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was about to start doing this to make it work: http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server

Unfortunately now i have the problem, that postgresql doesnt start!
When i try using "sudo gitlab-ctl tail postgresql" it says this:

"postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory"

Comment: And of course the same problem occurs when using sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Comment: Okay, i reinstalled gitlab now with the following commands:

#Complete uninstall of gitlab#
sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
sudo apt-get remove gitlab-ce
sudo apt-get purge gitlab-ce

And then remove the rest of the gitlab files manually with:

sudp rm -rf /opt/gitlab/

After that just install the omnibus package again. At least postgres seems to work now. Going to follow the steps in my link above now to allow gitlab to work on apache.

Comment: I think removing and re installing was the best way to go. If it works please consider adding all those steps as an answer to this question.

Comment: Yes it it rly was.
But now i have still a problem, even after configuring all apache .conf files and the gitlab.rb, the site does not show up. 
Instead i see the default plesk site.. should i open another thread for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so what i did now is just a complete reinstall of gitlab (which did not really solve the problem). Because now, even after configuring apache like they said here: http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server
On git.codefighters.org, there is just the plesk default page showing up. I guess im going to open another thread for that.

This is what i did for the complete re-install of gitlab:

## Complete uninstall of gitlab

sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
sudo apt-get remove gitlab-ce
sudo apt-get purge gitlab-ce

And then remove the rest of the gitlab files manually with:

sudp rm -rf /opt/gitlab/

After this, postgresql is working fine again and i could configure th gitlab.rb and apache config files.

Comment: I can see git.codefighters.org is running well, good job! What did you end up doing? Also what base server image did you use to install GitLab over?

Comment: Hey dude, sorry i was on holiday! :D
Here is another thread in which i solved my problem, hope it helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421385/gitlab-site-is-showing-the-plesk-default-page-what-am-i-doing-wrong?noredirect=1#comment56602621_34421385